# Google places API authorization error

Tags: android, google-places-api

I used this [tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/) to get address in autocompletetextview as suggestions. I activated Google Places API and generated Android Key. But when I run the app I get this error `This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address <IP>, with empty referer`. Is there something I'm doing wrong. If any one can help me in this regard, it would be great. Thanks.

[image: I got this error as link in logcat]

[image: credentials]

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    //------------ make your specific key ------------
    private static final String API_KEY = "<GooglePlaceAndroidKey as in credentials>";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.query);

        autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&components=country:gr");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());

            System.out.println("URL: "+url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {

            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                System.out.println("============================================================");
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList<String> resultList;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: have you use serverkey for place API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not enabled Geocoding service. To get Place google require Geocoding enabled.

[Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=_)

select [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/geocoding_backend/overview?project=_) and Enabled it.

Comment: I got the error resolved by using server key instead of android key. I also enabled `Google Maps Geocoding API` thanks to you. But problem now is  I only get suggestions of specific places. When I search for Delhi, I'm not getting anything. I'm adding screenshot also. @Pratik

Comment: Can you pls try to remove API key parameter and make WS call?

Comment: I tried but got error message `This service requires an API key.` @Pratik

Comment: I got complete result: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&components=country:in&input=delhi

Comment: i found issue in your code.     
            sb.append("&components=country:gr"); replace with           sb.append("&components=country:in");

Comment: No problem. Understood the problem. I'll remove the country parameter Thanks a lot. @Pratik

Comment: Can you suggest any tutorial for using url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=delhi&key=xyz` in Android   ?